# Does Firestore increment() have min/max support?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `FieldValue.increment()` to add or take away from a total.

However, is there a way to only perform the increment "up to" a certain value, meaning to increment until hitting that value and no higher?

Likewise, is there a way to go "no lower than" a certain value, meaning to increment negative value down to something like 0, but no lower?

The only way I can see enforcing this is by going around the atomic guarantee that using `increment()` provides.

It would be great if increment() accepted a 2nd param of allowable range:

```
{ min: 0, max: 100 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#increment

You can run a `transaction` to do a read/write and support your conditional logic.

Comment: Thanks, this looks just like what I was looking for:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions